# What is this system of coordinates and how to convert to lat lon with R?

Tags: r, utm, epsg

I am not familiar with geographic coordinates systems.

**Initial data**

I found these data, and I know that the position is in Paris, but I don't know how to "read" them.

```
603536, 2429320
```

**Systems of coordinates**

With https://epsg.io, I found the approximate location of this point with two very common systems:

- EPSG:32633 WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N `X: -424216.403492 Y: 5489351.63476`
- EPSG:4326 WGS 84 : `longitude: 2.3845325°, latitude: 48.8622053°`

**Questions**

My questions are :

- How to read this: `603536, 2429320` ?
- How to convert this to lat long ?

Comment: Please only ask ONE specific question at once. Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system ?

Comment: Even though you've been here a while, you still haven't taken the [tour].. It explains how "chit-chat" is discouraged, and how there should be **one** question per Question. Please [edit] this question to remove the initial paragraph and focus on the question you want to ask. Qustions like "What is a UTM zone?" are not appropriate, since that would show no attempt to solve the issue on your own.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this online tool to convert between coordinate systems: https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/

If you have the time, and absolutely no metadata (data about your data) then you could set the source to WGS84 and input the coordinates you have above and then go through a few target coordinate systems until you find one that matches.

To answer your other questions, you really need to study up on a bit of reference material.

The 'Zone' for a Universal Transverse Mercator projection UTM is a section of the world, divided vertically, (running from equator to pole, hence N or S for north and south). The way UTM works, distance gets distorted after a while, so it's divided into zones that minimise this. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system

To answer your actual questions, in order to read those coordinates, you need to know the coordinate reference system they are defined in. Once you know this, you can use a variety of 'reprojection' or 'transformation' tools to change the coordinates from that one coordinate reference system to a new one, say, WGS84 in Latitude/Longitude.

Comment: thank you Alex, the number of coordinates of systems is quite impressive. I will try to look at some...

Comment: Hi @XRSC, yes, there are many of the used currently or at some time in the past across the world! This is why finding metadata is rather important.